# Object destructuring in map function

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

Below is the component I am working on:

```
//PURPOSE : Component to show some useful information about the current page. like LAST REFRESH TIME OF DATA.
//Props that needs to be passed. - {MessageTitle}
//
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../../css/BubbleInfoComponent.scss";
import ApiHelper from "../../api/ApiHelper";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
const BubbleInfoComponent = (props) => {
  let [Info, setInfo] = useState({});
  function onClicko() {
    console.log("Handling Click");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [Info]);
  function getData() {
    ApiHelper.GetLastRefreshTime(props.uid).then((response) => {
      // const infoData = response.data.map(({sysName, lastRefreshTime}) =>{
        // return (sysName ? <div key={sysName}>`{sysName}:{lastRefreshTime}`</div>): <div>{lastRefreshTime}</div>;
      // })
      // setInfo(infoData);
      // console.log("infoData:- ")
      // console.log(infoData);
    });
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div id="Bubble__Circle" onClick={onClicko}>
        <p>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="info" color="#30343f" />
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="Bubble__Content">
        <div id="Bubble__Content_Msg_Title">{props.MessageTitle}</div>
        {/* <div id="Bubble__Content_Msg_Title">{Info}</div> */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default BubbleInfoComponent;
```

There will be two kind of JSON response I will be getting:

> 1. {
>    "SystemA": "07-04-2021 08:00",
>    "SystemB": "07-04-2021 08:00",
>    "SystemC": "07-04-2021 08:00"
>    }
> 2. {"responses": "07-04-2021 08:00"}

What I want to implement is 1st type of  response I want to set the value of `Info` in `"Key": "Value"` format and for 2nd type of response only time should be visible.

I hope I made my point clear. I know I did something wrong while destructuring in line21, this might look silly but being a newbie to JavaScript, I am not able to identify where i am going wrong.

Comment: My bad.. I have made the correction

Comment: Are two kinds responses you have listed the ones coming from the GetLastRefreshTime or they what you want to convert to?

Comment: @UdenduAbasili Both type of responses will come from GetLastRefreshTime.

Comment: so what error are getting exactly? i can deconstruct it but seeing as i can't exactly know what line 21 is from your snippet, I would like to know the error. Based on your responses, your sysName is not defined. I know that SystemA is your sysName but it is not called sysName in your object

Comment: These are line 21 and 22 : 
// const infoData = response.data.map(({sysName, lastRefreshTime}) =>{
        // return (sysName ? <div key={sysName}>`{sysName}:{lastRefreshTime}`</div>): <div>{lastRefreshTime}</div>;  In here also conditional statement is not correct which I am trying to fix

Answer (score 0):

Map function can be run on arrays and not objects. So the first thing which has to be done is to convert object into and array. For that you can use the Object.entries which will give you the key and values for each of the elements in the object.

Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Based on the response type you either access the time directly or run through a map. Here is the code to start with :

```
ApiHelper.GetLastRefreshTime(props.uid).then((response) => {
    const mapSystemNames = (data) => Object.entries(data).map(([key,value]) => <div key={key}>{key}:{value}</div>)
    const infoData = response.data.responses? <div>{response.data.responses}</div> : <div>{mapSystemNames(response.data)}</div>;
  // setInfo(infoData);
  // console.log("infoData:- ")
  // console.log(infoData);
});
```

Probably there may be some edge case scenarios / type checks needed to make it more robust, but this could get you started in the right direction. Please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: I am able to capture the response. I can see that in chrome dev tools network tab, But enabling `setInfo(infoData)` is calling the api infinitely.

Comment: That is because you have passed info as the second argument in useeffect which basically tells the effect function to run whenever info changes and that function getData in turn updates info causing an infinite loop. Pass empty array as the second argument in useEffect